# Why UIImageView does not render image in UIView?

Tags: swift

I am able to set system image as a button icon and add subviews under views but whatever I try, UIImageView never renders a system image. What am I doing wrong?

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "pencil")
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    }
```

Comment: the code is posted on its own is OK, something else is not working for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `UIImage(systemName: "pencil")` initializer instead of `UIImage(named: "pencil")` in order to use images from SFSymbols. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/3294233-init).